# How to insert a whole line into a node in c?

Tags: c, linked-list, getline

How to using getline() to get a whole line and insert it into linked list?
Here is my code. I am sure whether I can look a line as a whole string. When I tried only one line, the program is working with no problem. But when I tried to insert another line it shows me Segmentation fault: 11.

```c
typedef struct Node{
    struct Node *next;
    char *data;
}Node;

void insert(Node **head, char *input){
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = input;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    Node *cur = *head;
    if(*head == NULL){
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else{
        while(cur!=NULL){
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        cur->next = newNode;
    }
}

void Pint(Node *head){
    Node *cur = head;
    while(cur!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n", cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main(){
    Node *head = NULL;
    char *input = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    while(getline(&input, &len, stdin)!=EOF){   
        insert(&head, input);
        input = NULL;
    }
    Pint(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try moving 
    cur = cur->next; below 
    cur->next = newNode;

Comment: @user2519193 It seems like it has a infinite loop now...

Comment: Change the while loop to an if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the seg fault is when you do:

```
    while(cur!=NULL){
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    cur->next = newNode;
```

Since cur is NULL after the while loop, it doesn't have a next.

In the while loop, I would check when cur->next is not null, that way when you assign the newNode to cur->next, cur will not be NULL.

That would explain why the first one worked, since it just set *head = newNode, but then the seg fault occurs when you add the next one.